# Google chrome - how to activate google chrome and switch to specific tab window?

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, autohotkey, hotkeys

On windows system, i have Python/QT GUI running. Now on button push i need to activate minimised or not minimised google chrome in front of my application.

How to activate Google chrome and then switch to a very specific TAB by `static title name` or `process id titles` (using Python or other way)?

(For example activate the second tab)
[image]

Python: (does not work it is only working to open it)

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://docs.python.org/'
chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

Ahk: fails

```
#d::
list := Acc_Get("Object", "4.23.1", 0, "ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")
;MsgBox % list.accChildCount-1
for each, tab in Acc_Children(list) {
   MsgBox, % tab.accName(0)
   tab.accDoDefaultAction(0)
}
Return


#c::WinActivate( "Calculator", "calc" )

#NoTrayIcon
#SingleInstance force

WinActivate( TheWindowTitle, TheProgramTitle )
{
    SetTitleMatchMode,2
    DetectHiddenWindows, Off

    IfWinExist, %TheWindowTitle%
    {
        WinGet, winid, ID, %TheWindowTitle%
        DllCall("SwitchToThisWindow", "UInt", winid, "UInt", 1)
    }
    Else
    {
        Run %TheProgramTitle%
    }
    Return
}
```

**TRY TOO:**

```
If ChromeHasTabNamed( "Activating Chrome Tab" )
    MsgBox, Yes
Return


ChromeHasTabNamed( X ) {
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    WinGetTitle, title, - Chrome
    While Not InStr( list, title "`n" ) {
        list .= title "`n"
        ControlSend,, ^{Tab}, - Chrome
        Sleep, 50
        WinGetTitle, title, - Chrome
    }
    Return, InStr( list, X ) ? True : False
}
```

**TRY till DIE:**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinWaitActive - Google Chrome
ControlFocus, Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1
Loop, 15
{
   WinGetTitle, Title, A  ;get active window title
   if(InStr(Title, "Gmail")>0)
   {
      break ; Terminate the loop
   }
   Send ^{Tab}
   Sleep, 50
}

return
```

Comment: webbrowser is not intended as an equivalent to products like autohotkey. If you want to use Python to control the mouse and send keystrokes look for products like PyWinAuto, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works.

```
chrome := "- Google Chrome"
found := "false"
tabSearch := "Gmail"
curWinNum := 0
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinGet, numOfChrome, Count, %chrome% ; Get the number of chrome windows
WinActivateBottom, %chrome% ; Activate the least recent window
WinWaitActive %chrome% ; Wait until the window is active
ControlFocus, Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1 ; Set the focus to tab control ???
while (curWinNum < numOfChrome and found = "false") { 
    WinGetTitle, firstTabTitle, A ; The initial tab title
    title := firstTabTitle
    Loop {
        if(InStr(title, tabSearch)>0){
            found := "true"
            break
        }
        Send {Ctrl down}{Tab}{Ctrl up}
        Sleep, 50
        WinGetTitle, title, A  ;get active window title
        if(title = firstTabTitle){
            break
        }
    }
    WinActivateBottom, %chrome%
    curWinNum := curWinNum + 1
}

if(found = "false"){
    Run "https://gmail.com"
}    
return
```

Comment: Change the first "break" to "return"; if there are more windows active then after the loop WinActivateBottom is called even if the tab was already found, which results in the next window to be activated.